# Internet user - 网民? 互联网用户?

Tags: mandarin, vocabulary

The question is simple – do these two terms mean the same thing? I have seen the first one translated as a "netizen" once, but do they principally mean the same thing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 网民/netizen seems to be very specific to the PRC, and only used in political context, e.g. in an "online protest" the Internet users are "netizens". It's a very idiosyncratic word, and almost exclusively used for Chinese Internet users in the PRC, as if they were a different kind of "species".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually use the term 网民 to describe  "people who use the internet frequently".  The literal translation of 网民 is " web resident"

互联网用户 just means "internet user". If you have access to the internet, even if you check your email once a week, you are still an internet user.

Comment: Similar to netizen vs net user vs internet user vs web user, these terms are interchangeable.